# How to smooth data of a line chart in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, charts, highcharts, smoothing

I have a CSV data generated with PHP, coming from RRD data :

```
timestamp,traffic_in,traffic_out
2017-01-23 16:35:00,-2268249.77,1907141.89
2017-01-23 16:40:00,-2268249.77,1907141.89
2017-01-23 16:45:00,-918995.8,891413.25
2017-01-23 16:50:00,-918995.8,891413.25
2017-01-23 16:55:00,-1298763.3,1278968.96
...
```

And I make charts with it. All works well ... BUT ... there is too much data for a "fancy" chart.
I know I can lower RRD step/resolution, but then I really lose interesting data.

This is what I get currently :
[image: Chart BEFORE]

And this is ABOUT (sorry for poor drawing) what I would like to get. **"IP" means Important Point, it is about the only points to keep in the CSV.**
[image: Chart AFTER]

I spent a lot of time to filter the series, for example by discard values if the value is below (a tenth of) standard deviation from last value, or with a (max - min) percentage, but it is always ugly or losing important data.

Can you please help me do this in PHP ?

Regards

Comment: You could look at Signal Smoothing Algorithms: http://195.134.76.37/applets/AppletSmooth/Appl_Smooth2.html or maybe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting

Comment: I know your question was almost 3 years in the past.
But have you checked PHPs function trader functions? e.G.:  trader_sma(), trader_sqrt()

I stumbled across your question as I’m facing a similar issue to smooth out temperature charts without missing important dips and peaks. 

Wikipedia has also some basic information about the different common smooth algorithms. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing

@stpoa also mentioned a good resource.